# Using arrays to do basic calculations with negative exponent

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, exponent

I'm trying to write a function which outputs the correct result when multiplying a number by a negative power of ten using arrays and `split()` method. For example the following expressions get the right result: `1x10^-2 = 0.01` `1x10^-4 = 0.0001`.

Problem comes when the number's length is superior to the exponent value (note that my code treats `num` as a string to split it in an array as shown in code bellow :

```
//var num is treated as a string to be splited inside get_results() function
//exponent is a number
//Try different values for exponent and different lengths for num to reproduce the problem
//for example var num = 1234 and var exponent = 2 will output 1.234 instead of 12.34

var num = '1'; 
var sign = '-';
var exponent = 2;
var op = 'x10^'+sign+exponent;

var re = get_result(num);

console.log(num+op +' = '+ re);


function get_result(thisNum) {
    if (sign == '-') {
    var arr = [];
    var splitNum = thisNum.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i <= exponent-splitNum.length; i++) {
      arr.push('0');
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < splitNum.length; j++) {
      arr.push(splitNum[j]);
    }
    if (exponent > 0) {
      arr.splice(1, 0, '.');
    }
    arr.join('');
  }
  return arr.join('');
}
```

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/Hal_9100/c7nobmnj/

I tried different approaches to get the right results with different `num` lengths and `exponent` values, but nothing I came with worked and I came to the point where I can't think of anything else.

You can see my latest try here : https://jsfiddle.net/Hal_9100/vq1hrru5/

Any idea how I could solve this problem ?

PS: I know most of the rounding errors due to javascript floating point conversion are pretty harmless and can be fixed using `toFixed(n)` or by using specialized third-party librairies, but my only goal here is to get better at writing pure javascript functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where you push the decimal point `.`

instead of

`arr.splice(1, 0, '.');`

try this:

`arr.splice(-exponent, 0, '.');`

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/c7nobmnj/1/

Comment: Thank you ! I don't know why I didn't think of it. It works perfectly fine now !

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you want to keep going with the array approach to a solution, but it seems like this could be solved with using the Math.pow() method that already exists.

```js
function computeExponentExpression ( test ) {
  var base;
  var multiplier;
  var exponent;
  
  test.replace(/^(\d+)(x)(\d+)([^])([-]?\d+)$/, function() {
 base = parseInt(arguments[1], 10);
    multiplier = parseInt(arguments[3], 10);
    exponent = parseInt(arguments[5], 10);
    return '';
  } );
  
  console.log( base * Math.pow(multiplier, exponent));
}

computeExponentExpression('1x10^-4');
computeExponentExpression('1x10^2');
computeExponentExpression('4x5^3');
```

Comment: Thank you. Even though I don't want to use Math.pow due to its rounding errors, you showed me a very interesting way to parse the expression string.